# How to install sailfin on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, java, relinux

I want to install [sailfin](https://sailfin.java.net/) on ubuntu for my project.

Comment: Sure, what package type is it? Can you give us a link? What is Sailfin? What happens when you type `sudo apt-get install salfin` ?

Answer (score 0):

Installing  and implementing the MCU media server is a quite in depth process, which is far too exhaustive to answer here without duplicating most of the [official installation guide](http://sourceforge.net/p/mcumediaserver/discussion/853498/thread/cd5c7054/f2c7/attachment/Installation%20and%20configuration%20guide.pdf).  The applications need to be configured manually based upon your own requirements and preferences.

The official [sourceforge project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcumediaserver/) has a wealth of resources including active forums and links to source code that can assist you.